# How can I implement an sqlite3 virtual table module in Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite

I am familiar with the process of creating a virtual table module in C and C++ for linux, macosx, and Windows.  I would like to understand the process for doing the same on Android.

Specifically:

1) Does this involve writing a C/C++ module and integrating in to my android project [ I use Android Studio ]

2) Is it possible to write a vtab module in Java?

I have searched for any references to this question, and can find nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mechanism is not exposed in the Android database API.

You'd have to compile your own copy of the SQLite library and use it through the NDK.

Comment: That's not a problem (since I usually create my own sqlite library anyway).  Thanks!